# Помогите с SQL запросом

Tags: php, sql

Пытаюсь написать в PHP SQL запрос, который должен выбрать из БД 1 значение каждых повторяющих чисел, никак немогу с этим справиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выбрать в id_num каждый 2 по счету с num. В num не всегда счет идет одинаково, но это не важно. Главное есть счет всегда больше 5. Например в числах 5 нужно выбрать id_num = 3 в 7 нужно id_num = 5 в 8 это id_num = 34 и так далее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для mysql. Строим временное поле с порядком в группах num отсортированных по возрастанию id и выбираем те строки, в которых это поле соответствует второй строке

```
 select num, id_num 
    from (SELECT id, id_num,
                 @order:=IF(num=@snum, @order+1, 0) ord, 
                 @snum:=num num
             FROM t,
                  (select @snum:=0,@order:=0) t1
            ORDER by num, id) t2
  where ord=1
```

[Демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7b13/1)

Comment: Работает, то что нужно) спасибО0

Comment: Рад помочь. Удачи!

Comment: Можешь еще подсказать как мне пронумеровать строку num в новой строке типа [так](https://i.gyazo.com/363b56ec81c599ad0d220c7197d42f4c.png)

Comment: так подзапрос, я так понимаю, делает то, что вам надо в поле ord

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/8867bcc3997ab941860f6ad5aeae0475.png - у меня вот такая таблица) а в демке вы добавили еще id а у меня этого нет и я чуть запутался(( несмог правильный запрос сделать

Comment: я не в демке добавил - он у вас в вопросе есть. Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: вмеcто id - id_t_p

Comment: Понял) вроде норм работает и еще 1 запросик нужен, нужно выбрать первые пять значений по повторяющимся цифрам. тоесть не вторую только а первые 5. А то что-то я не смог переделать ваш запрос так чтобы выбирать сначала 1 потом 2 и так до 5 ))

Comment: `where ord < 5`

Comment: Где это добавить ?))
`select id_post, id_tag from (SELECT id_t_p, id_tag,
                     @order:=IF(id_post=@snum, @order+1, 0) where ord < 5, @snum:=id_post id_post
                     
                FROM tag_post,
                     (select @snum:=0,@order:=0) t1
                ORDER by id_post, id_t_p) t2
                where ord=1`

Comment: Похоже что увидел где))

Comment: там где ord=1 поменять на другое условие

Answer (score 1):

2 варианта, либо опишите задачу более чётко.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_num = 34 или
 SELECT * FROM table OrderBy num
```

Comment: Вот так  https://i.gyazo.com/5c2dc869e606f19b5e07026f92aca145.png