# Трехтабличный SQL-запрос: извлечение товара и соответстующих ему тэгов

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть три таблицы базы данных по которым нужно составить фильтр.

1. таблица `tag (id_tag, tag)` в котором есть все теги вместе (в кучку)

[image: Таблица tag]

2. `tag_post (id_t_p, id_tag, id_post, num_tag_inpost)`

[image: Таблица tag_post]

3. `post (id_post, post)`

[image: Таблица post]

Пример: если хотим вынуть один товар с этих таблиц нужно взять с таблицы `tag_post` c 1 до 8 например для `id_post` поста 5 вынуть все айдишники `id_tag` и с таблицы `tag` вынуть по этим айдишника теги то получиться один товар типа `1) артикул 2) Вид изделия  3)Материал  4) Основная вставка  5) Производитель` нам важно только айдишники до 5

Делаю фильтр на php. И очень затрудняюсь с составлением SQL запроса(
[Аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522443/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC) в котором хотел вынуть товары с БД. Потом решил добавить в БД нумерацию с 1 до сколько то там повторяющихся цифр чтобы запрос был простым. 
[image: Как выглядит фильтр]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос. Вы оформили характеристики товара как теги через связь многие-ко-многим.

1. Для "экономного" вывода списка товаров можно хранить значения тегов прямо таблице `post` в большом текстовом поле (тип TEXT подойдёт) в сериализованном виде. Тогда в простых запросах *без фильтрации по тегу* не понадобятся сложные JOIN-ы.
   Так поступает сам stackoverflow!
2. Фильтр *по любому из* указанных тегов возможен как `… WHERE tag_post.id_tag IN(1,3,5)`
3. Фильтр *по всем* указанным тегов потребует максимум работы, поэтому покажу подробно.

Получить список айдишников товара, у которого имеются все нужные характеристики, то есть перечисленны нужные теги:

```
SELECT id_post 
FROM tag_post
WHERE id_tag IN (1,3,5)
GROUP BY id_post
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Во фразе HAVING указываем число тегов, которое у нас в скобочках IN() — в примере их 3.
Если нужны поля из `post`, используем этот запрос как под-запрос:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post AS p JOIN
(
  SELECT id_post 
  FROM tag_post
  WHERE id_tag IN (1,3,5)
  GROUP BY id_post
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) AS tpg USING(id_post)
```

Answer (score 3):

Для получения тэгов, соответствующих товару, можно воспользоваться запросом

```
SELECT
  p.post AS post,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT t.tag ORDER BY tp.num_tag_inpost
  ) AS tags
FROM
  post AS p
JOIN
  tag_post AS tp
ON
  p.id_post = tp.id_post
JOIN
  tag AS t
ON
  tp.id_tag = t.id_tag
WHERE
  p.id_post = 5
GROUP BY
  p.id_post
```

Для получения товаров, соответствующих набору определенных тэгов, например, с идентификаторами `tag_id`: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, можно воспользоваться таким запросом

```
SELECT
  p.post AS post
FROM
  post AS p
JOIN
  tag_post AS tp
ON
  p.id_post = tp.id_post
WHERE
  tp.id_tag IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY
  p.id_post
```

Comment: По этому запросу я получаю 1 товар. Как бы сделать чтобы получать  все товары по которым ввели теги в инпуты фильтра чтобы потом их отфильтровать по данному фильтру!? Например пользователь вводит название 5 тегов а я через GET отправляю их айдишники и вынимаю соответсвующие товары

Comment: @pwnz22, поправил ответ.

Comment: Что-то не совсем то( я отправляю айдишники тегов а тут ищет значения которые в таблице post по айдишникам id_post, tag_id Это id_tag?

Comment: Сначала ищутся тэги в таблице tag_post, а потом по связанным с ними ключам id_post ищутся товары.

Comment: А если я отправлю несколько значений id_tag с одного инпута то запрос такой же мне нужен будет?

Comment: Да, нужно будет просто подставить их вместо 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 в конструкции IN

Comment: Когда я ввожу 2 разных тега которые в одном посту оно выводит сначала все теги по первой айдишке а потом по второй, нельзя как нибудь отфильтровать чтобы выводил посты в которых есть только эти 2 тега вместе а не всё в кучку!? типа когда пользователь ищет 1 конкретный товар по 5 тегам

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39807/discussion-between-pwnz22-and-cheops).

Comment: Такое возможно вообще с моим БД?